# Changing the wordpress permalinks for particular posts

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a google blog with Custom domain. It is gaining reach now. So I'm planing to take it to the next level. I tried several site but didn't get what I was expecting. I want my wordpress to have the same URL of my blogger. But the new post which I'm posting in wordpress should have wordpress URL structure. Example
My blogger URL >> www.catholicgallery.org/post-name.html for the imported blog post
and www.catholicgallery.org/new-post-name/ << Expecting this for the new posts.

Kindly help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Try this plug-in - https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Answer (score 1):

You can set same blogger URL name using this two plugin if you want to.
1. Custom Permalink(Change url as you want).
2. WP Page Extension(Convert url to html).